# Yii2. Kartik select2 Как включить русский язык?

Tags: yii2, kartik

Не могу включить русский язык в виджете. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В виджете язык включен [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках приложения то же [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Языковой файл подгружается [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда еще можно посмотреть? В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге приложения надо так указывать `'language' => 'ru-RU',`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Вероятно в месте вызова виджета надо указать также.